# ASP.NET Core RC2 403.14 Forbidden error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET Core test website on my Windows 10 machine. I followed the steps found in the ASP.NET Core documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html), but when I browse to the site, I get a 403.14 Forbidden error. I can Run the app through Visual Studio, fine and everything is rendered as expected, but when I Publish the site, the error appears. A few other items:

- The root of the site is pointing to the wwwroot folder of the published output as it should be.
- I can place a static file in the wwwroot folder and access it through the browser fine. Problem only seems to happen when browsing to MVC code. When enabled, directory browsing works fine as well.
- Routing, controllers, and views are set up correctly. I can Run and Debug the site in VS fine with an instance of Kestrel running.
- I am trying to access the site via port 80 on a test URL specified in my hosts file (I am hosting a number of other sites fine on the same machine already with this common config).
- The app pool is configured correctly using No Managed Code.
- The IIS instance has full file permissions to the folder.

I am thinking I have something messed up in my installation (I had a previous install of HttpPlatformHandler installed previous to the RC2 where it was replaced by AspNetCoreModule). Any thoughts?

Comment: In RC2 web.config should be in the parent of the wwwroot and this is where you application should be rooted - https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/173. Static files should not be served by IIS but by your application using the StaticFiles middleware. I wrote a blog post about using ASP.NET Core apps with IIS you might find helpful: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Comment: I have the same problem... tried everything